# ¿Como agregar un parametro a la URL de Liferay?

Tags: java, eclipse

Estoy utilizando el hook del inicio de sesión, junto con el servicio wrapper **UserLocalServiceWrapper** de liferay 7 el cual tiene el siguiente método:

```
@Override
public int authenticateByEmailAddress(long companyId, String emailAddress, 
                                      String password, Map<String, String[]> headerMap, 
                                      Map<String, String[]> parameterMap,
                                      Map<String, Object> resultsMap) throws PortalException {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.authenticateByEmailAddress(companyId, emailAddress, password, headerMap, parameterMap, resultsMap);
}
```

La pregunta es la siguiente, como puedo yo enviar un parametro propio a la URL de Liferay, no se si alguno de los parametros del metodo de arriba pueda servirme, ya que necesito obtener mi parametro que envio en otro portlet.

Gracias...